# How can I tell what apache rewrite rules are being applied to my requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess

I am working on a rails app that is hosted on a shared server. The app is on a subdomain: database.my_domain.org. I had some rewrite issues when I was setting it up, detailed in this post: [Extra directory prepended to my routes in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193943/extra-directory-prepended-to-my-routes-in-production)

Now I am having a potentially related but ultimately different problem. Whenever a user tries to edit or create an object in the app, they get a "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" error. I can see in the log what is going wrong: the app starts a request to one address but it is executed as a request to a different address:

```
Started PUT "/individuals/4" for 72.93.46.141 at Tue Oct 07 10:54:37 -0400 2014

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/4"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.18) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

This started unexpectedly one day when nobody was working on the app. I have rolled back my rails code to a previous version and this did not fix the issue, so I am fairly certain the rails code is not the problem.

The .htaccess file in the root directory of my subdomain (~/public_html/database) looks like this:

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/user/ruby/gems
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/rails_apps/app_name/current/

RewriteEngine Off
```

I don't see any way this could still be re-writing my urls.

On the other hand, the .htaccess file in ~/public_html (one directory up) contains all kinds of rules. I don't think they are being used though. I backed-up and then deleted the file and the issue was still occurring. Here is the ~/public_html/.htaccess file if it helps:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

#old links
redirect 301 /shop /chocolate_shop
redirect 301 /shop /chocolate_shop
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/4 /chocolate_shop

redirect 301 /pg/show/id/1 /our_philosophy
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/2 /our_story
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/3 /our_vision

redirect 301 /pg/show/id/4 /chocolate_shop
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/32 /chocolate_menu
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/5 /family
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/6 /garden
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/28 /garden_what_we_grow
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/23 /garden_a_typical_day
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/7 /festival
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/8 /catering
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/27 /catering_menu

#people pages
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/1 /people?johndoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/2 /people?janeplain
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/4 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/5 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/8 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/9 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/11 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/19 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/20 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/21 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/22 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/23 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/24 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/26 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/27 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/28 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/29 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/30 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/31 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/34 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/42 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/43 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/44 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/45 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/46 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/47 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/48 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/50 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/51 /people?joeshmoe
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11/person/52 /people?joeshmoe

redirect 301 /pg/show/id/11 /people
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/12 /learning
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/13 /events

#updates pages
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/36 /feed
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/17 /news

#give pages
redirect 301 pg/show/id/14 /give
redirect 301 pg/show/id/15 /volunteer
redirect 301 pg/show/id/16 /goods
redirect 301 pg/show/id/30 /volunteer_form

#policy page
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/34 /privacy

#search page
redirect 301 /pg/show/id/35 /search

# Internally rewrite URLs requested with no filetype to php scripts
# unless the requested URL resolves to an existing directory or file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.shtml [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  #RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^phillycatering\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.phillycatering\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/my_domain\.org\/chocolate_shop" [R=301,L]
```

Are rewrite rules inherited in sub-directories? Is there any way to tell what apache rewrite rules are being applied to my requests?

Answer (score 0):

They're inherited to the subdirectories unless you have different rules in your subdirectory. By default, the rewrite engine is OFF, so turning it off doesn't change anything. Instead, you need to turn it *on* but have no rules.

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/user/ruby/gems
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/rails_apps/app_name/current/

RewriteEngine On
```

This tells the rewrite engine that you want the rewrite engine to be on and apply any rules you have in this directory context (which is none), and that effectively supercedes any rules you have in a parent directory.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: @lucas the only other thing I can think of is adding a `RewriteRule ^database/ - [L]` to the very top of your parent htaccess file.

Comment: That's a good idea. It didn't change anything still, but I think at least that eliminates the possibility that rules might be getting inherited from the parent htaccess file.